# Unable click button by xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

This is the code I have

```
<button type="button" id="B-New" data-sap-ui="B-New" title="Add New Order" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" class="sapUiBtn sapUiBtnNorm sapUiBtnS sapUiBtnStd">Add</button>
```

`xpath` for this is `"//*[@id='B-New']"`

I am trying to click the button but unable to so.

I have used xpath, ID class name everything but it is unable to click.
This is what I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='B-New']")).click()
```

Kindly help.

I have also used javascript

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('B-New').click()");
```

but it also doesn't work.

Comment: This is the complete code             <td id="__cell3" class="sapUiMltCell sapUiMltPadRight" style="overflow:hidden" data-sap-ui="__cell3">
<button id="B-New" class="sapUiBtn sapUiBtnNorm sapUiBtnS sapUiBtnStd" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="button" title="Add New Order" data-sap-ui="B-New" type="button">Add</button>
</td>

Comment: What do you mean by unable to click?? Is there any exception?? Need to share it as well..

Comment: Yes there is Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='B-New']"}

Comment: Ok I have provided you the answer try it and let me know the result...:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible and enable to click as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("B-New")));
el.click();
```

**Note** :- If this element is inside any `frame`, you need to switch that frame before finding and clicking the element using `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id")`.

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Yes I try this way but still it is not able to click the button and showing the error unable to locate element

Comment: Is this throws `NoSuchElementException` or `TimeoutExcpetion`??

Comment: No such element exception

Comment: Saurabh Gaur thanks for the support I am able to click the button using sikuli

Comment: @dimple But if you are getting No such element exception  means you are not using `WebDriverWait` with my provided answer to find element because If you use `WebDriverWait` it throws `TimeoutExxeption` instead..so please use as it is given my example may be it helps.. Thanks

Comment: @Saurabf Gaur this is the exception that I got org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: B-New

Comment: @dimple please check the flow of execution as well. Make sure the `click` operation is called when the element is visible in the screen logically. As it throws exception even after waiting I suspect this may the reason.

Comment: @AnandThanappan I have tried wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("B-New"))).click(); but still it shows Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: B-New

Comment: @dimple and what about frame or iframe??did you look for this??

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur There is no frame and iframe in the code actually it is sap based UI and code is written in java script you can have a look in my first comment that I have provided earlier

Comment: @dimple ok, once you open browser console by pressing f12 and execute this `document.getElementById('B-New')` and let me know the result...:)